# How to create project in testswarm

Tags: testswarm

I've successfully installed testswarm on my machine.

I just can't find how to create project and start running some tests. On GUI there is no option for creating a project.

There is a text on login "Login for projects. Projects can only be created by swarm operators.". So, how to create swarm operator and/or project?

Answer (score 1):

You create a project using

`php scripts/manageProject.php --create=true --id="yourtestid" --display-title="your display title here"`

This script creates a project and requires an id and a display title, and also has optional options for site-url and password. The create flag tells the script to create the project if it doesn't already exist.

The script will return an auth token (which can be re-created with scripts/refreshProjectToken.php).

This needs to be done from the server where testswarm is installed.